# Disjoint language extensions (C++ and Objective-C)

Tags: language-design, c, c++, objective-c

Objective-C and C++ are both extensions of C (or at least started out to be). So for the purpose of this question I allow myself the slightly inaccurate assumption that both languages are pure supersets of C. They have this interesting property, that their syntax extensions added to plain C are disjoint, in the sense that any C++ language construct that is not valid C has no meaning in Objective-C and vice versa. This allows for the hybrid language Objective-C++ to exist.

I have a few questions about this:

- Is my understanding stated above correct? Are they really completely disjoint?
- Did this happen on purpose or by chance? I would assume by chance because it would be a weird feature to plan in from the beginning, but it also seems unlikely to simply have happenend by chance.
- Are there any other languages that exhibit a similar phenomenon?

Comment: Having disjoint syntax doesn't necessarily mean the semantics are compatible. You would have to define what it means to call a C++ function with a value which only makes sense in Objective-C, and vice versa. Or of course you could forbid this entirely with the type system, but then that would presumably defeat the purpose. Point is, having non-overlapping syntax doesn't say much about whether two languages could work together as a hybrid.

Comment: @kaya3 As I understand, objects in Obj-C are opaque C-pointers (like `void*` or similar), and Obj-C function can also take plain old C-structs as parameters, so they could at least communicate via the shared C constructs. So even if combining the language extensions would be forbidden, this is still valuable to bridge between C++ and Obj-C code. And you can have C++ objects as members of Obj-C classes (and vv I think)

Comment: `id` can’t be converted directly to `void*` without a bit of work, because `id` is ARC’d and `void*` isn’t. However, you’re right about putting one type of class inside the other. I’ll also note that the two languages aren’t _perfectly_ compatible, because C++ changes the meaning of `auto`.

Comment: What is the basis of your assumption that the syntaxes are disjoint? Is this just something you have observed personally?

Comment: @BruceAdams Yeah, pretty much. And the fact that they can coexist and interact in one file. But if that's not true in general that would make a great anwer :)

Comment: You appear to be asking two separate questions here. One about objective-c++ and one about the more general phenomenen. It might improve your question to be specific about which question you really want answered, though I have tried to answer both.

Answer (score 2):

### Polyglot programs & Dialecting

This does not really answer the intent of your question which is I think if there are extension languages that are deliberately disjoint from each other but there is something called a [polyglot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing)) program
where the same source file can be parsed correctly into two or more completely unrelated languages.
Mostly this is more like programming golf.
The only practical use I can think of is bootstrapping a dos or shell script to run something else.
For example:

```
#!env python
```

If we talk about languages where independent extensions are part of the design then the [rebol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebol) family (including [red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_(programming_language))) is worth looking at.
These languages have the concept of [dialecting](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Rebol_Programming/Language_Features/Dialects).
Dialecting essentially means the language contains a number of mostly independent DSLs (dialects) each specialised for a particular function.

In Rebol one of these is a dialect (parse I think) which is used to define other dialects.

Prolog has a similar feature in that you can write [definite clause grammers](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg) but its not as directly accessible.

I can't answer for the specific case of C++ and objective-C myself but [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3684159/1569204) suggests it was intentional:

> you might want to read Apple's (sadly deleted, but archived) documentation on [Objective-C++](https://web.archive.org/web/20101203170217/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html).